# Android: Finding if service is running or not from widget after app is killed

Tags: android, android-widget, android-service

I have a service in my app that does some tasks. Also I have a WidgetProvider class. When the app is killed I stop the service via stopSelf(). After this if user interacts with the widget, I need to know if service is running. How can I do that?

Boolean variables in widget class don't work since it is just a broadcast receiver. Also Shared Preference is not working since my app is killed and so I get null pointer exception. In such case how can I find out if the service is running or not? Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need to check if the services is running or not. You could just `startService` in the AppWidgetProvider, and it will start the service if not already started. But if you still need to check if the service is running or not, then you could use `SharedPreference`. `SharedPreference` is common to your Services, Activity and WidgetProvider, since all of them belong to the same application. I am not sure why you are getting a `nullpointerException`.

When you call `stopSelf()` or in the appropriate life cycle of the Service like `onDestroy()` may be you could write to `SharedPreferences` about the state of the Service in a boolean. You can then read from this `SharedPreferences` in the `onReceive()` or `onUpdate()`.